# How to prove$|\cdot|^{s}g\in\mathcal{S}'$? a question from Bahouri-Chemin-Danchin book "fourier analysis and nonlinear pde"

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, fractional-sobolev-spaces

In page 27 and 28 of book ***"fourier analysis and nonlinear partial differential equations"***, proposition 1.36 the authors Bahouri-Chemin-Danchin give a proof of this proposition, but I really don't know how to prove $|\cdot|^{s}g\in\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{d})$? Any suggestions or hints are wellcome, thanks! [image]

Comment: We can proceed as follows:

By Proposition 1.34, when $|s|<\frac{d}{2}$, $(-\Delta)^\frac{s}{2}\mathcal{F}g \in \dot{H}^{-s} \subset\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $g\in\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. (You can also use a density argument if you prefer, see Proposition 1.35).

The Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}$ being an automorphism on $\mathcal{S}'$, it tells us that

$$ |\cdot|^s g \in\mathcal{S}'$$

for all $g\in\mathrm{L}^2$, all $|s|<\frac{d}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you @ToGle, you help me a lot!!!! Your hint is so insightful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall $ f \in \mathcal{S} ' $ provided $  \lvert  \langle  f, \phi \rangle  \rvert \leq C\sum \rho _{\alpha,\beta}(\phi) $ where $ \rho _{\alpha,\beta} $ are the seminorms and the sum is over a finite indexing set. Then as $g \in L^2 $ so $ \lvert \xi \rvert^s g$ is a function so it induces a distribution via integration so we just check $\forall  \phi \in \mathcal{S} : $
\begin{align*}
      \lVert   \lvert \xi \rvert^s g \phi \rVert_{L^1} &\leq  \lVert  \phi \rVert_{L^\infty} \lVert   \lvert \xi \rvert^s g \rVert_{L^1(B_1)} + \lVert  \langle \xi \rangle^N \phi \rVert_{L^\infty} \lVert   \lvert \xi \rvert^s \langle \xi \rangle^{-N} g \rVert_{L^1(B_1^c)} \\
      &\leq \lVert  \phi \rVert_{L^\infty} \lVert   \lvert \xi \rvert^s \rVert_{L^2(B_1)} \lVert  g \rVert_{L^2} + \lVert  \langle \xi \rangle^{ N} \phi \rVert_{L^\infty}  \lVert   \lvert \xi \rvert^{s - N} \rVert_{L^2(B_1^c)} \lVert  g \rVert_{L^2} 
\end{align*}
where we choose $N$ large enough so $\lVert   \lvert \xi \rvert^{s - N} \rVert_{L^2(B_1^c)}< \infty$. So the only thing we have to make sure is finite is the $\lVert   \lvert \xi \rvert^s \rVert_{L^2(B_1)}$ term. But
$$  \lVert   \lvert \xi \rvert^s \rVert_{L^2(B_1)} = \lVert   \lvert \xi \rvert^{2s} \rVert_{L^1(B_1)}^{\frac{1}{2}} =C \lVert  r^{2s  + d - 1} \rVert_{L^1(B_1)}^{\frac{1}{2}} < \infty \iff 2s + d - 1 >  - 1 \iff 2s + d > 0 \iff s >  - \frac{d}{2} \impliedby  \lvert s \rvert < \frac{d}{2}.  $$

Comment: thank you for your answer! In the last line, according to your answer, when $s>\frac{d}{2}$(that is to say, we take a larger $s$), we also have $\||\xi|^{s}\|_{L^{2}(B_{1})}<\infty$. But in this case, $s>\frac{d}{2}$ and so $s$ does not satisfy $|s|<\frac{d}{2}$. I am confused in this place, can you help me more? Thank you!

Comment: Oh, maybe you should say $|s|<\frac{d}{2}$ firstly, then according to this to conclude that $\||\xi|^{s}\|_{L^{2}(B_{1})}<\infty$?

Comment: @monotoneoperator I have used the symbol $\impliedby$ to denote $|s| < d/2$ is being used to ensure $s > - d/2$. I didn't write it first because I wanted to show where the assumption was being explicitly used.

Comment: thank you! I get it